# Drupal 8 - User Account Mail

Tags: email, drupal, user-registration

I have some issue with User Account Settings. (Drupal 8)
Normaly there is a possibility to change the content on every mail...but it's does not work.
If an user register to my website (from a front form) a different email is send than the one i configure here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpfTy.png)

Someone ?

Answer (score 0):

The **`Welcome (new user created by administrator)`** email template (as its label says) is for accounts created by admin, not for users who manually register on your site.

The email template your users are receiving is **`Welcome (awaiting approval)`** or **`Welcome (no approval required)`**, depending on whether administrator approval is required or not.

[image]